# Logging Persian messages with NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have below config in Web.config as below:

```xml
 <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="default" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/app-log.txt" layout="
--------------------- ${level} (${longdate}) ----------------------$
IP: ${aspnet-request-ip}
Call Site: ${callsite}
${level} message: ${message}"/> archiveFileName="logs/archives/app-log.{#}.txt" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="7" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="default" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

If my log message is in Persian text then in log file I have question mark as `?????` instead of the Persian text.

How can I fix this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: try specifying encoding="utf-8" or encoding="utf-16" attribute in target element

Comment: I added encoding="utf-8" to the target element and unfortunately I have text as ==> Error message: Ù†Ù…Ø§ÛŒÙ†Ø¯Ù‡ Ø§ÛŒ Ø¨Ø§ Ø§ÛŒÙ† Ø§Ø·Ù„Ø§Ø¹Ø§Øª Ø«Ø¨Øª Ø´Ø¯Ù‡

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added `encoding="UTF8"` attribute in target element
for example:

```
<target name="FileLogger" xsi:type="File" encoding="UTF8" layout="....">
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ramesh pointed out tru using `Encoding="utf-16"` and also try `writeBom="true"`.

The nlog documentation of this file target is https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target and it might give you some more help.

Comment: No, sorry friend. I did all of them but it still gives me ==> Error message: Ù†Ù…Ø§ÛŒÙ†Ø¯Ù‡ Ø§ÛŒ Ø¨Ø§ Ø§ÛŒÙ† Ø§Ø·Ù„Ø§Ø¹Ø§Øª Ø«Ø¨Øª Ø´Ø¯Ù‡

Comment: Can you post an example of the text here or share the location of a document with some of the text in and I will try and work it out for you.

Comment: I am out at the moment and will take a look when I get home (6-8 hrs time)

Comment: logger.Error("مشکلی در بررسی درخواست شما رخ داده است")

Comment: Ok friend. I changed the text

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I solved it by changing encoding="utf-8" to encoding="UTF8"